# What Ways Are There To Store Passwords in iOS (For Jailbroken Apps)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, jailbreak

I have been looking into this a lot and people only mention the iOS Keychain. However, I have one issue with storing passwords with the keychain:

- For what I have read, the keychain behaves differently based on how you codesign your application. Since I don't codesign applications, I'm afraid I will find many stones while I try to use the Keychain without any signing profile.

So what other alternatives are to store passwords in iOS? I'm making two apps that really need to be pass-locked for the user.

Comment: What do you mean by pass-locked to the user?  When I first run your app I create a password? Or do you want some kind of registration system where only registered users can use the app?

Comment: Think of a "Diary" app. You wouldn't like anyone to access that app. But yeah, when someone first runs my app, create a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Keychain in one of my apps and I used SFHFKeychainUtils classes which just make it easier to use Keychain. Refer to this blog:

http://gorgando.com/blog/tag/sfhfkeychainutils

Keychain is a secure way to store passwords since the storage values are encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

In your example of a "Diary" application, there is no need to store the password.  Just use [symmetric-key algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) to the encrypt and decrypt the data.  Therefore only the user knows the password, not even your app.

To Save:

- Covert the "Diary" objects to NSData
- User types in password to encrypt NSData
- Write the encrypt NSData to file

To Load:

- Read the encrypt NSData from file
- User types in password to decrypt NSData
- Convert NSData to "Diary" objects